Perl regex for street number street name, at least, one digit, one upper case letter, least two lowercase and one whitespace
I know this won't be perfect but I am looking for a regex to take a guess if a line in a file is a street address (w/o city state zip).
For example:
112 N Main
3525 Webster
1 Stone Ave
Morrison Number 34
So the recipe I am shooting for is:
at least one digit,
at least one upper case letter,
at least two lowercase letters
and at least one white space somewhere in the middle of the string.
So far what I have is unsuccessful:
/[1-9][A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\s/


What's your goal? Are you extracting addresses for some use, looking for malformed addresses to correct, performing textual analysis? Think about what @briandfoy says in relation to your use's importance and frequency. I handle addresses professionally for such uses as newsletters to nonprofit organization members and election campaign mailings to voters. Parsing addresses is challenging even when you KNOW the string of characters is an address; recognizing an address out of arbitrary text is even more tricky.

The pattern that you tried must match in the specified order, and does not handle that the mandatory characters are present in any order.
You might use:
^(?=[^\n\d]*\d)(?=\h*\S+\h+\S)(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z])(?:[^a-z\n]*[a-z]){2}.*

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
(?=[^\n\d]*\d) Assert a digit using a negated character class ( the \n is there no not cross newlines)
(?=\h*\S+\h+\S) Assert a horizontal whitespace char between 2 non whitspace chars
(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z]) Assert an uppercase char A-Z
(?:[^a-z\n]*[a-z]){2} Match 2 lowercase chars a-z
.* Match the rest of the line

See a regex demo
Note that in your regex you don't have to use the {1} as that is default, and if you want to match a digit 1-9 instead of 0-9 then you can change \d to [1-9]
Using \s can also match a newline, I have used \h to match a horizontal whitespace char but you could change that of course.

with the /x flag, you can add insignificant whitespace to your pattern and add comments right in the pattern. And, a .* at the end doesn't help at all since there is nothing that is will reject.

@briandfoy The .* at the end matches the rest of the line if you are processing the matched strings. If you are just checking if there is a match then you don't need it. Personally I am not a fan of the /x flag, I am just used to writing it as a single line.

You could make a huge regex, but that is usually a mistake that you'll regret later (probably like trying to validate addresses at all):
$_ = $address =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g; # remove leading and trailing whitespace
if( /\d/a && /[A-Z]/ && /[a-z].*+[a-z]/ && /\h/ ) {...}

Now, you might want to check that the characters so up at the beginning of a "word", so you can throw some word boundary assertions in there. The Unicode idea of word boundary, \b{wb} is probably most appropriate:
if( /\b{wb}\d/a && /\b{wb}[A-Z]/ && /[a-z].*+[a-z]/ && /\h/ ) {...}

But, these patterns are likely to change or expand. Move the pattens out of the logic so you don't obscure what you are doing. Now you can add and subtract from the array without disturbing how you decide an address is bad:
my @patterns = ( qr/\b{wb}\d/a, ... );
my $misses = grep { $address !~ $_ } @patterns;
if( $misses > 0 ) { ... } # bad address

And, @patterns could even come from external config. This is something I write about at length in Mastering Perl.
However, there is more bad data that will match this than actual addresses. And, consider the usual case the the input is every form of mistake or inconsistency that a person will type out:
If there is a lowercase letter at the start, do you capitalize it for them:
1234 main st 

I know of a town full of street numbers that have letters in the middle, and what if they leave off the suffix?
15S30 4th    

And Queens, NY is just crazy. The first set of digits (21) represent the nearest cross street and the second the house number. But, 21st Ave isn't called 21st Ave (it's Ditmars).
21-32 33rd

And this is just the US. The UK system has no particular rhyme or reason and some addresses do not have digits, either spelling out the number or having no number since the building is named.
There are entire industries built just around address normalization and validation. It's not a set of complex rules, but a set of sets of historical, regional, or hyper local knowledge. The US Postal Service has a free service (with limits), as do some other post offices. Google has a service that will do it. There are so many weird cases that it's not something you want to think about on your own.

Thanks Brian for the very instructive reply. Always good to hear from you.

For this particular application the US addresses come pretty well standardized so the regex rules above pretty well fit my needs and I can tweak them as needed. For another application, that checks if an address is a duplicate before inserting it into a DB I have written a number of standardization rules, for example /ln/Lane/ /W/West/ /N./North/, etc in a module that I call Strings.pm, then I use Text::Levenshtein to flag entries over a certain %. It works pretty well and I can add rules as needed. It's all internal code that only a few employees use so it's a well controlled environment.
